# How to get authorized token for Youtube analytics with Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-analytics-api

i want to get an authorized token for my App Script Application for YouTube Analytics.. Currently i am using cGoa Library to get an Authorized token which requires authentication once as provided in [this link](https://mashe.hawksey.info/2017/10/getting-youtube-analytics-with-google-apps-script-when-you-get-authentication-loops/) .. But for security purpose, we don't want to use external script like the so called cGoa Library. Please i need to know any other ways to acquires Oauth2 access token for YouTube Analytics in Google App Script. Our major objective id to have the token once and for all future uses because we want to automatically run the script on a daily basis. So we need something that will works all time without require more authentication. Currently this is the code i use to get token with cGoa Llibrary.

```js
function oneOffScript() {
  var options =  {
    packageName: 'youtube-analytics', // user defined
    clientId: '942097727718-t663ep631aqhd75610g4etpcn3foj827.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    clientSecret:'Ng_9HJ34hKSPesvRA6hb85KR',
    // following method to add Google scopes. Here we are mixing YouTube Data and Analytics (prefixed yt-) 
    // in the same service allowing calls to both APIs with the same token (we can do this because both are Google APIs)
    // More on mixing services http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/goa/mutipleconsent
    scopes : cGoa.GoaApp.scopesGoogleExpand (['youtube',
                                              'youtube.force-ssl',
                                              "youtubepartner",
                                              "youtubepartner-channel-audit",
                                              "yt-analytics-monetary.readonly",
                                              "yt-analytics.readonly"]),
    service:'google' // always this for Google APIs. Ref: http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/goa/services
  };
  // store one off in user properties
  cGoa.GoaApp.setPackage(PropertiesService.getUserProperties(), options);
}
 
function doGet(e) {
  var goa = cGoa.GoaApp.createGoa ('youtube-analytics',
       PropertiesService.getUserProperties()).execute (e);
   
  if (goa.needsConsent()) {
    return goa.getConsent();
  }
```

Please your response is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How about using manifests? By putting 6 scopes you use to the manifests file, you can retrieve the access token including the scopes using ``ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()``. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Tanaike , Thank you for your responce.. But i don't understand how the manifests file would help me accomplished my goal, if i save all the 6 scopes to the manifest file, how can i authorized access for once and then save the token to manifest for all future uses.. Please i need you to enlighten me more. Thank you.

Comment: I'm really sorry my comment was not useful for your situation.